# How to request curid or pageid when searching by Wikipedia API?

Tags: json, wikipedia-api

I am trying to search for a given term on the Wikipedia API and am able to retrieve a list of titles and snippets, but I want the JSON to also include the Wikipedia "curid" or "pageid" so I can use that for links.

[Here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search) is the (unhelpful) documentation as far as I can tell, and here is what I have so far:

```
var jsonresult=null;
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&utf8=1&srsearch=Einstein&callback=?", 
        success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
        jsonresult = result;
        printAjax(result);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log("oh no");
        }
    });
}
```

I don't know how to change the API request URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get "pageid" try [query](https://bg.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query) with **generator** instead **list**, and use [extracts](https://bg.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bextracts) property for text snippet:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&utf8=1&gsrsearch=Einstein&prop=extracts&exintro=1&exlimit=20&exchars=200
```

Comment: Thank you for saving me hours of searching!!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use the url query in the ajax request and append the percent encoded title from the returned object `encodeURI(data["query"]["search"][index]["title"])` to `"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"` and use that for your page links.